# ValueError: Layer model_2 expects 2 inputs, but it received 1 input tensors

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, masking

I have this model I built and it is throwing the error in the title at `model3.add(graph)`. From what I have read and understood, the second model which is `model3` here expects two inputs at `model3.add(graph)` but it is only received one. Why does it need 2 inputs?
Am I overlooking something? Please help?

```
inputs3 = model.inputs[:2]  # We are getting all layers EXCEPT last 2 layers
layer_output3 = model.get_layer('Encoder-12-FeedForward-Norm')).output  #this is a layer from a pretrained BERT model
removed_layer = RemoveMask()(layer_output3)    #the previous layer contains masks which are not compatible with a CNN layer in Keras
conv_blocks = [] 
filter_sizes = (2,3,4)
for fx in filter_sizes:
    conv_layer = Conv1D(100, kernel_size=fx,
                                    activation= 'softsign'), data_format='channels_first')(removed_layer)  
    maxpool_layer = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(conv_layer)
    flat_layer = Flatten()(maxpool_layer)
    conv_blocks.append(flat_layer)
conc_layer = concatenate(conv_blocks, axis=1)
restored_layer = RestoreMask()([conc_layer, layer_output3])
graph = Model(input=inputs3, outputs=restored_layer)

model3 = Sequential()
model3.add(graph)
model3.add(Dropout(0.1))
model3.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model3.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model3.summary()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are combining a Functional Model(graph) with Sequential Model(model3). Either convert both the model to be Functional Model(like graph) OR convert both the model to be Sequential Model(like model3).

You can find solution for converting Functional model to Sequential Model and vice versa [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61130836/convert-functional-model-to-sequential-keras).