# ValueError: Layer sequential_20 expects 1 inputs, but it received 2 input tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build a simple Autoencoder using the KMNIST dataset from Tensorflow and some sample code from a textbook I'm using, but I keep getting an error when I try to fit the model.

The error says `ValueError: Layer sequential_20 expects 1 inputs, but it received 2 input tensors.`

I'm really new to TensorFlow, and all my research on this error has baffled me since it seems to involve things not in my code.
[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61006764/valueerror-layer-model-2-expects-2-inputs-but-it-received-1-input-tensors) wasn't helpful since I'm only using sequential layers.

Code in full:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#data = tfds.load(name = 'kmnist')

(img_train, label_train), (img_test, label_test) = tfds.as_numpy(tfds.load(
    name = 'kmnist',
    split=['train', 'test'],
    batch_size=-1,
    as_supervised=True,
))

img_train = img_train.squeeze()
img_test = img_test.squeeze()

## From Hands on Machine Learning Textbook, chapter 17

stacked_encoder = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[28, 28]),
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="selu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="selu"),
])

stacked_decoder = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="selu", input_shape=[30]),
    keras.layers.Dense(28 * 28, activation="sigmoid"),
    keras.layers.Reshape([28, 28])
])

stacked_ae = keras.models.Sequential([stacked_encoder, stacked_decoder])
stacked_ae.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
                   optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1.5))

history = stacked_ae.fit(img_train, img_train, epochs=10,
                         validation_data=[img_test, img_test])
```

Answer (score 36):

it helped me when I changed:
`validation_data=[X_val, y_val]`  into `validation_data=(X_val, y_val)`
Actually still wonder why?

Answer (score 15):

Use `validation_data=(img_test, img_test)` instead of `validation_data=[img_test, img_test]`

Here the example with encoder and decoder combined together:

```
stacked_ae = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[28, 28]),
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="selu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="selu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="selu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(28 * 28, activation="sigmoid"),
    keras.layers.Reshape([28, 28])
])

stacked_ae.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
                   optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1.5))

history = stacked_ae.fit(img_train, img_train, epochs=10,
                         validation_data=(img_test, img_test))
```

Answer (score 15):

As stated in the Keras API reference ([link](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/)),

> **validation_data**: ... validation_data could be: - `tuple` (x_val, y_val) of Numpy arrays or tensors - `tuple` (x_val, y_val, val_sample_weights) of Numpy arrays - dataset ...

So, **validation_data** has to be a tuple rather than a list (of Numpy arrays or tensors). We should use parentheses (round brackets) `(...)`, not square brackets `[...]`.

According to my limited experience, however, **TensorFlow 2.0.0 would be indifferent to the use of square brackets, but TensorFlow 2.3.0 would complain about it**. Your script would be fine if it is run under TF 2.0 intead of TF 2.3.

Comment: I was using Google Colab and I got the same error in the question. Typing `%tensorflow version 2.x` fixed the tensorflow version to 2.0 rather than 2.3 and then it worked! (using `(` rather than `[`). How do you fix this when using tensorflow 2.3? Simply changing parenthesis didn't work with tf 2.3

Answer (score 2):

You have given data instead of labels two times:

```
history = stacked_ae.fit(img_train, img_train, epochs=10,
                         validation_data=[img_test, img_test])
```

instead of

```
history = stacked_ae.fit(img_train, label_train, epochs=10,
                         validation_data=[img_test, label_test])
```

Comment: This is autoencoder which is semi-supervised, not typical ML problem. that's why no need to pass separate labels.

Comment: But this is autoencoder, so labels are not passed at model fit.

Answer (score 1):

In solutions, some says you need to change from bracelet to parentheses, but it was not working in Colab. And yes, turning`validation_data=[X_val, y_val]` into `validation_data=(X_val, y_val)` should work since it's required format, but in tf==2.5.0(in Google Colab) it doesn't solve the problem. I changed from functional API to sequential API, that solves the problem. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

This error may also be triggered by submitting the wrong object to `model.fit()`.  It happened to me when I mistakenly tried to execute

```
model.fit(images)
```

when I wanted to execute

```
model.fit(dataset)
```

with

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images, images))
```