# why may code generates the error while i fit the model" ValueError: Layer "sequential_3" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network, layer, sequential

while I am trying to fit the model on Quora dataset this error generated. please help me. i am a very beginner in this field

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
#create the embedding layer
#len(embeddings) = 85790, embeddingDim = 300
e = Embedding(len(embeddings), embeddingDim, weights= 
[embeddings],input_length=maxSeqLength,trainable=False)
#embedding_layer = Embedding(total_words, embedding_dim, weights=[embedding_matrix], 
input_length=max_length, trainable=False)

from tensorflow.keras.models import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(e)
model.add(SimpleRNN(128,activation='relu',return_sequences= True))
model.add(SimpleRNN(256,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
print(model.summary())

model.fit([X_train['left'], X_train['right']], Y_train,epochs=5,validation_data= 
([X_validation['left'], X_validation['right']], Y_validation))
```

Answer (score 0):

`validation_data` needs to be a tuple, as stated in the Keras API reference ([link](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#:%7E:text=distribute.experimental.ParameterServerStrategy.-,validation_data,-%3A%20Data%20on%20which)):

> **validation_data**: ... validation_data could be: - `tuple` (x_val, y_val)
> of Numpy arrays or tensors - `tuple` (x_val, y_val, val_sample_weights)
> of Numpy arrays - dataset ...

> A tuple `(x_val, y_val)` of Numpy arrays or tensors.
> A tuple `(x_val, y_val, val_sample_weights)` of NumPy arrays.

Reference to a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63604307/10145479

Comment: I think the validation parameter in the above code is in tuple validation_data= 
([X_validation['left'], X_validation['right']], Y_validation) . even when i remove the validation parameter the same error is showing!

Comment: Sir, can you help me in another ways? as this solution didn't work.